# Move S3 bucket to another region

Tags: amazon-s3

I want to move a S3 bucket from Tokyo to Seoul, and I don't want to re-create it. Is there any way doing this? (Move region without deleting and recreating) If not, what should I keep in mind?

I don't want to make another bucket to dump it temporarilly, syncing it, and then deleting/recreating in another region, and sync it again.

Comment: I do not want to delete it, therefore 'duplicate' is not an option for me.

Comment: S3 bucket names are globally unique - the same bucket name cannot exist in two different regions.

Comment: I don't want to delete/recreate it and just move its location. You're saying it's impossible?

Comment: Doing it the way you want is impossible.